# Get index of object in a list using Linq

Tags: linq, list, indexing, find, indexof

I am new to Linq. I have a Customers table.ID,FullName,Organization,Location being the columns. I have  a query in Sqlite returning me 2500 records of customers. I have to find the index of the customer where ID=150 for example from this result set. Its a List of Customers. The result set of the query is ordered by organization. I tried with FindIndex and IndexOf but getting errors for the former and -1 for the latter. So, how should it be done?
Thanks.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You don't need to use `LINQ`, you can use [`FindIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/x1xzf2ca.aspx) of `List<T>`:

```
int index = customers.FindIndex(c => c.ID == 150);
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know about this method

Comment: Too bad this is not defined as a LINQ method and thus is only useful when working with a true pure `List<T>` rather than any `IList<T>`.

Comment: You have also [`Array.FindIndex<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03y7c6xy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper could apply this to most IEnumerables or ObservableCollections to a list by just using .ToList().FindIndex()

Comment: @Wilhelm: I rather dislike the idea of evaluating the entire enumeration if the element I'm looking for might be among the first couple of items. Also, note that there is *never* a good reason to use `ToList()` in situations where an array (as can be obtained from `ToArray()`) would do as well.

Answer (score 37):

Linq to Objects has overloaded [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) method

```
customers.Select((c,i) => new { Customer = c, Index = i })
         .Where(x => x.Customer.ID == 150)
         .Select(x => x.Index);
```

Keep in mind, that you should have in-memory `List<Customer>` to use this Linq to Objects method.