# Reading several elements using Linq-to-Xml and some loop?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

With the following code, I'm currently reading `<ns>CounterSales</ns>` (the 3rd element) of every `<nv>`, which is great. I'm including the code and the XML.

Here's the code, works great if `ElementAt` is hardcoded :

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlStr);
var nvs = xDoc.Descendants("nv");
var nads = nvs.Select(nv => nv.Elements("nad").First().Value).ToList();
var thirdRs = nvs.Select(nv => nv.Elements("r").ElementAt(2).Value).ToList();
```

Here's the value of `xmlStr`:

```
<ni>
    <nss>20150927</nss>
    <gp>Addon</gp>
    <ns>CounterBlah1</ns>
    <ns>CounterBlah2</ns>
    <ns>CounterSales</ns>
    <ns>CounterBlah4</ns>
    <ns>CounterBlah5</ns>
    <ns>CounterBlah6</ns>
    <nv>
        <nad>Style=1,Rfu=1,Id=132</nad>
        <r>0</r>
        <r>15</r>
        <r>8</r>
        <r>3</r>
        <r>2</r>
        <r>2</r>
    </nv>
    <nv>
        <nad>Style=1,Rfu=1,Id=433</nad>
        <r>0</r>
        <r>15</r>
        <r>30</r>
        <r>3</r>
        <r>2</r>
        <r>2</r>
    </nv>
    <nv>
        <nad>Style=1,Rfu=1,Id=665</nad>
        <r>0</r>
        <r>15</r>
        <r>90</r>
        <r>3</r>
        <r>2</r>
        <r>2</r>
    </nv>
</ni>
```

But let's say that I would like to read more than one counter. I have a datatable that currently has two rows: `[CounterSales]` & `[CounterBlah5]`. I would like to process the other two counters the same way:

```
int index = 0;
DataTable results = GetCounters();
//results has two rows: [CounterSales] & [CounterBlah5]

foreach (DataRow row in results.Rows)
{
    string counter = cellRow["counter"]; //counter equals "CounterSales"
    /* Iterate through all <ns> to see where "CounterSales" is located.
       In this case, index = 2. On next foreach, index equals 4  */

    var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlStr);
    var nvs = xDoc.Descendants("nv");
    var nads = nvs.Select(nv => nv.Elements("nad").First().Value).ToList();
    var thirdRs = nvs.Select(nv => nv.Elements("r").ElementAt(index).Value).ToList();
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: So whats the problem?

Comment: Instead of having `ElementAt` hardcoded to a value (2 in this case), I want to retrieve the actual index of the counter. In this example, for "CounterSales" `index = 2;`. With "CounterBlah5", `index = 4;`

Comment: how should it know what index the counter is at?

Comment: In the XML, there are 6 `<ns>` elements. "CounterSales" is the 3rd `<ns>`, so index would equal 2. In the next `foreach` run, "CounterBlah5" is in the 5th `<ns>`. So index would equal 4.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, this is what you need

```
DataTable results = GetCounters();
//results has two rows: [CounterSales] & [CounterBlah5]

foreach (DataRow row in results.Rows)
{
    string counter = cellRow["counter"]; //counter equals "CounterSales"
    /* Iterate through all <ns> to see where "CounterSales" is located.
        In this case, index = 2. On next foreach, index equals 4  */                

    var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlStr);

    //here we find the index
    var requiredIndex = xDoc.Descendants("ns")
            .Select((node, idx) => new { node, idx})
            .First(x => x.node.Value.Equals(counter)).idx;

    var nvs = xDoc.Descendants("nv");
    var nads = nvs.Select(nv => nv.Elements("nad").First().Value).ToList();
    var thirdRs = nvs.Select(nv => nv.Elements("r").ElementAt(requiredIndex).Value).ToList();
}
```

**Edit**: A shorter syntax to find index for `List<T>` from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18108778/get-index-of-object-in-a-list-using-linq) post.

```
var requiredIndex = xDoc.Descendants("ns").ToList().FindIndex(x => x.Value == counter);
```