# Unable to change foreach to LINQ syntax

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq, selenium

I am trying unsuccessfully to change the following loop to a LINQ expression:

```
int index = 0;
IList<IWebElement> divNota = new List<IWebElement>();

foreach (IWebElement element in tablaNotas)
{
    divNota.Add(element.FindElement(By.Id("accion-1-celda-0-" + index + "-0")));
    index++;
}
```

I tried using

```
IList <IWebElement> divNota = tablaNotas.Select(element => element.FindElement(By.Id("accion-1-celda-0-"+ tablaNotas.IndexOf(element) + "-0"))).ToList();
```

But `tablaNotas.IndexOf(element)`always returns `-1`, meaning the `element` was not found inside `tablaNotas`.

The string `"accion-1-celda-0-"+ tablaNotas.IndexOf(element) + "-0"` is meant to change to

```
"accion-1-celda-0-"+ 1 + "-0"
"accion-1-celda-0-"+ 2 + "-0"
"accion-1-celda-0-"+ 3 + "-0"
...
"accion-1-celda-0-"+ n + "-0"
```

In accordance to element's index

Any help is appreciated

Comment: There is a select overload where you can get the current index. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18108850/2961887

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
            var result = tableNotas
            .Select((element, index) => element.FindElement(By.Id("accion-1-celda-0-" + index + "-0")))
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Wow, this works perfectly. Could you point me to documentation about the index parameter in `(element, index)`? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @elgato: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.7#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32___1__

Answer (score 5):

In `Linq` some reserved word like `Where`, `FirstOrDefault` create a condition for your query and the `Select` reserved word can create your object that you want the `Select` method applies a method to elements. It is an elegant way to modify the elements in a collection such as an array. This method receives as a parameter an anonymous function—typically specified as a lambda expression.

**Example:** Let's look at a program where the Select extension method is applied to a string array. A local variable of array type is allocated and three string literals are used. We use Select on this array reference.

The basic method are here:

```
public static System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource,TResult> (this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource,int,TResult> selector);
```

Now! for this issue that you searched for that you can use of this code:

```
var divNotaResult = list
            .Select((data, index) => data.FindElement(By.Id("accion-1-celda-0-" + index + "-0")))
            .ToList();
```

In `Select` method do like `foreach` we have tow object in `function` **data** and **index**.

The `data` have each data in loop, and the `index` have count of loop.

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
var divNota = 
    tablaNotas.Select((element, index) => 
        element.FindElement(By.Id($"accion-1-celda-0-{index}-0")))
    .ToList();
```